# Is there a simulator for building circuits with Raspberry Pi GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio, windows, emulation, breadboard, design

I was wondering if there is a free simulator/emulator that I can run either online or on a Windows computer to let me test my scripts and more importantly my wiring, as I am new to building circuits.  I also need to be able to build the circuits in a 'real world' (breadboard) view as I find reading circuit layout very confusing and even more challenging to create.  The closest that I have found is Fritzing (http://fritzing.org) but they don't let me test my circuits and Autodesk Circuits (https://circuits.io/) but they only offer an Arduino emulator.

I currently do not yet own an actual Raspberry Pi nor all the components that I think I will need.

I thank you all in advance for any advice, and I apologize if someone else already asked this question.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to your question which makes the question off-topic for this site.

Comment: @joan I don't think it is irrelevant as I want to make sure that I am connecting my circuits correctly to the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins and that my scripts will correctly read/write to the pins.  The Raspbery Pi is an integral component in the circuit.

Comment: It's just my opinion, others may have a different opinion.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the function of a simulator. No program can test your wiring.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simulator for emulating the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi. Perhaps you could describe what you wanted to do in another question and we could tell you if it's likely to work.

Comment: Ok, I will work a bit more on how the circuits will work before asking for advice on my specific project.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the arduino simulator, and remember the Pi's GPIO pins have a signal voltage of 3V3 (like atmega168 pro mini 8MHz) and a recommended current output of ~8mA. You can probably get away with using a 1000 ohms resistor on all outputs.

Comment: I'll look into possibly using that Arduino for the simulator.